# How to show an alert message when data is inserted to database using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to show an `alert` when data is inserted into the database. this is the ajax code which sends the request to the `EditDeleteLecture.php`. but the main problem is that when data inserted it shows the `alert` in `Network pane`.

Ajax Code is that

```
function addRecord() {
    var formData = new FormData($("#form1")[0]); //It automatically collects all fields from form
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/EditDeleteLecture.php",
        type: "post",
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(output) {
            readRecords();
            $('#form1').trigger("reset");
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the `EditDeleteLecture.php` page which inserts the data into the database.

```
if (isset($_FILES['files']['name'])) {

    $files = $_FILES['files']['name'];
    $desc = $_POST['description'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $path = 'Lectures/'.$files;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"], $path);
    $date = date('d-M-y');

    $query = "INSERT INTO content(file_name,course_code,description,file_path,upload_date) VALUES ('$files','$subject','$desc','$path','$date')";

    $cm = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
    if ($cm) {
        echo '<script>alert("data Inserted Successfully");</script>';
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tIaW.png)

Comment: readRecords() what you do in this function?

Comment: then function shows record in the table

Answer (score 1):

write your alert in ajax success response like

```
function addRecord() {
    var formData = new FormData($("#form1")[0]); //It automatically collects all fields from form
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/EditDeleteLecture.php",
        type: "post",
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(output) {
            alert("record inserted successfully.")
            alert(output);
            readRecords();
            $('#form1').trigger("reset");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it is not possible because success is execute after your ajax request done successfully and response comes

Comment: try to alert your response like i have made edit in my answer

Comment: I said it shows the alert first. then insert data. why you don't understand

Comment: and if data is not inserted. then how can I show an error alert?

Comment: you can handle your error in error function of jquery ajax like you use success  https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-ajax-error-handling-function/

Answer (score 0):

Alert on ajax response

Update your php code with below code

```
if (isset($_FILES['files']['name'])) {
   $files = $_FILES['files']['name'];
   $desc = $_POST['description'];
   $subject = $_POST['subject'];
   $path = 'Lectures/'.$files;
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"], $path);
   $date = date('d-M-y');
   $query = "INSERT INTO content(file_name,course_code,description,file_path,upload_date) VALUES ('$files','$subject','$desc','$path','$date')";
   $cm = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
   if ($cm) {
      $result['status']="Succsess";
      $result['message']="Record Inserted Successfully";
   }else{
      $result['status']="failed";
      $result['message']="Somethink Went Wrong";
   }
 echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Check status in your ajax code

```
function addRecord() {
  var formData = new FormData($("#form1")[0]); //It automatically collects all fields from form
  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/EditDeleteLecture.php",
    type: "post",
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(output) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(output);
        if(json.status == "Succsess"){
           readRecords();
           $('#form1').trigger("reset");
           alert(json.message);
        }else{
          alert(json.message);
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: use this code console.log(output); and check in console what array return in output .

Comment: shows this {"status":"Succsess","message":"Record Inserted Successfully"}

Comment: but again it shows the message in Network pane, not in the alert box

Comment: maybe you have made spale mistake in alert(output.message);

Comment: have you chek in ajax call which alert is exicuted means if or else?

Comment: only the else is executed

Comment: I have upade answer with var json = $.parseJSON(output); just upade ajax inside the succsess code

Comment: @JohnMerry your problem is solved or still you facing issues?

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
    <script src=" js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#btnadd").click(function () {  
        var name,email,addr;  
        name=$("#t_name").val();    
        email=$("#t_email").val();    
        addr=$("#t_addr").val();  
        $.post("Insert.php",$("#fdata").serialize(),function(data){
          alert(data);
        $("#t_name").val("");    
        $("#t_email").val("");    
        $("#t_addr").val("");  

        })
    });
});  
</script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="border:4px solid yellowgreen;padding:2%;">
            <form id="fdata">
                Student Name
                <input type="text" id="t_name" name="t_name" class="form-control"/>
                Email Address
                <input type="text" id="t_email" name="t_email" class="form-control"/>
                Address 
                <input type="text" id="t_addr" name="t_addr" class="form-control"/><br>
                <button id="btnadd" class="btn btn-success">Save Record</button>
                <form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                
            </div>
           
        </div>
       
    </body>
    </html>
-----------------------------------------------------
<?php
$sid=$_GET["s"];
$cn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_at22");
if($cn==true)
{
    $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($cn,$_POST["t_name"]);
    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($cn,$_POST["t_email"]);
    $addr=mysqli_real_escape_string($cn,$_POST["t_addr"]);
    $res="update students set sname=$name,email=$email,addr=$addr where sid=$sid";
    if(mysqli_query($cn,$res))
{
    echo "Record Updated Successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "Record Not Updated";
}
}
else
{
    mysqli_error($cn);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).